# Redirecting inside an EventSubscriber at Shopware 6

Tags: shopware

How can I redirect inside an EventSubscriber, when creating a plugin?

I just subscribe to a specific event which inherits from `PageLoadedEvent`. In my method, I want just to redirect to another page.
For now, I can only redirect, overriding a controller, because only in the controller class, there are redirect-methods.
But I also just want to redirect, after a specific event was fired.

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace My\Plugin\Storefront\Subscriber;

use Shopware\Storefront\Page\Account\Profile\AccountProfilePageLoadedEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;

class Account implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
          AccountProfilePageLoadedEvent::class => 'onAccount'
        ];
    }


    public function onAccount(AccountProfilePageLoadedEvent $event) {

        /**
         * @var Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\RedirectController $redirectController
         */
        $redirectController = $this->container->get('Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\RedirectController');
        return $redirectController->redirectAction($event->getRequest(), "frontend.home.page");
    }
}
```

I found the `RedirectController`, which I can inject to my Subscriber via `services.xml`.
The result returns a `RedirectResponse`. But returning that object won't happen anything. It should redirect to the homepage.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `$response->send()` is that the processing would continue and the original response is still generated and tried to send. This fails with an error (headers already sent). So this appears to work at first glance, but is not a valid solution and also cannot be integration tested well.

The proper solution seems to first throw a custom exception and then catch it in the `KernelEvents::EXCEPTION` event to do the redirect.

This is how the core does it for the case, that the Customer is not logged in.

See [how the core defines CustomerNotLoggedInException](https://1.%20https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/a1c7e5f3f29318df041ab096389998fb600f040e/src/Core/Checkout/Cart/Exception/CustomerNotLoggedInException.php#L9-L9) and where it is caught.

The custom exception should be inherited from `Shopware\Core\Framework\HttpException`

```
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
...
        GenericPageLoadedEvent::class => 'onPageLoaded',
        KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => 'onException',
...


    public function onException(ExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        if(!$event->getThrowable() instanceof UnauthorizedException) {
            return;
        }

        $request = $event->getRequest();

        $parameters = [
            'redirectTo' => $request->attributes->get('_route'),
            'redirectParameters' => json_encode($request->attributes->get('_route_params'), \JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR),
        ];

        $redirectResponse = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('my.my-target.route', $parameters));

        $event->setResponse($redirectResponse);
    }

...

    public function onPageLoaded(PageLoadedEvent $event)
...

            throw new UnauthorizedException(302, 403, 'Unauthorized access to password protected page', ['location' => '/foo/bar/]);
...
        


...
```

A fully working example can be found in [an extension of ours](https://github.com/iMi-digital/shopware6-password-site/blob/5dede3cd55105fcbe83987226daf163f2f3a53e0/src/Subscriber/CheckPasswordSubscriber.php#L1).

Answer (score 0):

this is currently not possible if you subscribe to a PageLoadedEvent. I created a ticket for that in our internal issue tracker https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-5107

You could follow the state there.

In the meantime you could try to subscribe to `\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents::RESPONSE` and do the redirect here.

Best regards from Schöppingen

Michael Telgmann

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but it is possible with RedirectResponse:

```
\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
```

Example:

```
 //if you want to redirect to controller which does not acepts xmlhttp request, you can use 201 response code as second argument
$response = new RedirectResponse($path);
$response->send();
```

You can generate the path using Shopware Router (you can attach it by DI to your subscriber):

```
\Shopware\Storefront\Framework\Routing\Router
```

Example:

```
$path = $this->router->generate('frontend.checkout.cart.page');
```

Comment: Problem with `$response->send()` is that it is not well Integration-testable any more